# Created a VM but cannot open in powershell

Tags: linux, ssh, virtual-machine

Created few VMs but last one I created is giving me an error. when I try to connect to power shell it says:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

Comment: How are you trying to access the virtual machine? by SSH? which operating system manages the VM?

Comment: SSH through my student login

Comment: The SSH server tells you that the login must be done by `publickey`. In that case, you should have your key pair configured and the server should know the public key.